# event.preventDefault() on multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button, preventdefault

Is there a way to write `e.preventDefault()` once for every button on an app (perhaps by creating a function)? I understand how to prevent the default events from a button (link, etc):

```
<button onClick={e => e.preventDefault()} /> <!--For React, but it's the same elsewhere-->
```

However, I have many buttons on my app and I'm tired of writing it out for every button. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using inline javascript at all, but proper event handlers

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button'),
    fn      = function(e) { e.preventDefault() };

for ( var i = buttons.length; i--; ) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', fn, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The inline javascript was just for the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', e => e.preventDefault());
}
```

Comment: You might want to add some flavor text to improve your post.